Flowbite Datepicker format bug when using "dd.mm.yyyy" – incorrect date after day 12
I'm using Flowbite's Datepicker in my Blazor project and need the date format as dd.mm.yyyy (day, month, year). Here’s the relevant part of my code:
<InputText @bind-Value="Input.End" datepicker datepicker-format="dd.mm.yyyy" id="datepicker-range-end" name="end" type="text" class="..." placeholder="Select date end" />

The Datepicker works fine for days 1–12 of each month, but if I select a date with a day greater than 12 (for example, October 20, 2024), it unexpectedly changes to a different date after I tab out of the input field. For instance, selecting October 20, 2024, results in the field showing October 8, 2025.
Hypothesis: It seems like the Datepicker might interpret the format incorrectly, falling back to a U.S. date format (MM.DD.YYYY) whenever the day is greater than 12.
Has anyone encountered a similar issue with Flowbite’s Datepicker? Any advice on getting it to reliably use dd.mm.yyyy format or other workarounds would be appreciated.
